# Launch a program from ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, process

I have a program (I created) and I want to start it on the server when the webpage loads.

Here is the code I have

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Process app = new Process();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        app.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:/Path to /My/Program to be run.exe";
        app.Start();
    }
}
```

Right now the application is 'run' however it crashes instantly. 
If I just run the application (by double clicking the exe) it runs and everything is fine.

anyone see if i'm missing something here?

Comment: Is there any sort of error message when it crashes?

Comment: "_{application name}_ has stopped working. Windows is checking for a solution to the problem"

Comment: @John, that was a last ditch effort to make the app actually run. I dunno, i've been reading tutorials and staring at my old ASP.NET book and mucking around. Forgot to remove that before I posted my example code.

Comment: Anything in the Event Log on the error?

Comment: Are you using ASP NET Development Server?

Comment: I am new to ASP.NET, So Yes? but only Yes assuming that is the default Server VS2010 creates when you build the webpage.

Comment: Try setting more properties in the ProcessStartInfo object, like working directory.

Comment: Try creating a trivial Console application, and running that. This will eliminate the specific application from consideration.

Comment: Might bet a permissions thing as well. Although you'd think .NET would throw a security related error, you never know. I presume the identity/account that cassini runs under probably doesn't have adequate permissions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use ProcessStartInfo.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = @"D:/Path to /My/Program to be run.exe";
psi.WorkingDirectory = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(psi.FileName);
Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: He already did that, that's what his `app.StartInfo.FileName = @"...";` line is.

Comment: Worked! This works. However Why does it have to be invoked this way? what is the real difference (just so I am actually learning something and not just copy-paste your answer)

Comment: It may have been because you defined your `Process` variable outside `Page_Load`, or because you forgot the CWD.

Comment: @SpikeX, when I implemented this solution I moved the declaration for psi outside of the Page_Load, however I did forget the Working Directory..

Comment: Then that was the problem ;) The program you started must have relied on the CWD somehow.

Comment: @rlemon I don't think there's anything different other than informing the Working Directory property. However, since you've informed the path with the FileName Property, I don't think it should be really necessary. Anyways...

Comment: well defining the WorkingDirectory solved my problem and the app now starts without any errors.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the application you're trying to run has a user interface. If you're intention is to run this on the server using the ASP.NET application pool account, you will have fewer problems if you design the application as a console app, and guard all access to external resources, like your HMI device, with logged exceptions.

Comment: I will be converting the app to a console app eventually. I am completely new to ASP.NET and how it interacts with it's code behind. I am currently knee deep into a few ASP.NET books, learning slowly.

Answer (score 3):

This is a security issue. Running any exe from outside the bin folder poses a security threat. You have to copy the exe you are trying to run in the bin folder.

Comment: Can you grant access for a folder outside of .NET applications?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you're trying to run. Maybe when you run it from your C# app something's missing. You also might not have the correct permissions to run the app from C#. That's all I can really say without knowing what's trying to be run.

Comment: The app i'm trying to run has very few dependencies. It's a small HMI application I wrote to read values from a Serial Device and display them in a form. Now I want to open the app from a c#/ASP.NET webpage, read the values from the serial device connected to the server, store the data on a db or in a flat file and allow the user to display it now or at a later date.

Comment: For that, I recommends you to use a Windows Service to start up the program: this way the HMI can store the data in the database and later, in any application, you can show the data sorted by inserted datetime or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like this in Javascript :-

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
var appExe =  @"D:/Path to /My/Program to be run.exe";
shell.ShellExecute(appExe , "", "", "open", "1");
```