# How can I start external programs in C#?

Tags: c#

Hello I am making an application to be somewhat of a "dashboard" for all of the programs I have made so I can start them from this "dashboard" program. What code would I need to start these external programs.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See if the answer here helps. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209834/launch-a-program-from-asp-net-c-sharp

Comment: Grant, you need to ask only one question per post. You currently have 3 distinct and separate questions here.

Comment: Sorry I was not aware that you could only ask one question per post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string strProg= @"full file name of your program";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",strProg);
```