# Linq2Xml Remove specific attribute name and their values

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, xml

I have this XML, and i am trying to delete those:
`Name="items"`
`Name="shipmentsShipmentIndex"`

"Name" is not going to change,

The word that will be change is the word between the quotation marks, in this example: 
`items` and `shipmentsShipmentIndex`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <RootDTO xmlns:json='http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json'>
   <destination>
      <name>XXX</name>
   </destination>
   <orderData>    
      <items json:Array='true'>   
        <shipmentIndex Name="items">0</shipmentIndex>           
      </items>
       <items json:Array='true'>      
        <shipmentIndex Name="items">0</shipmentIndex>           
      </items>

      <shipments json:Array='true'>          
        <shipmentIndex Name="shipmentsShipmentIndex">0</shipmentIndex>                                                          
      </shipments>
   </orderData>
  </RootDTO>
```

How can i find all these occurrences and remove them(or replace them with nothing)?
I tried a bunch of variations like: `Name{1}[a-zA-Z]+"\b`

Comment: Try a basic replacement: `\bName="[^"]*"` => `Name="NEW_VALUE"`

Comment: According to what i see, its "A word boundary"

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew didn't understand you solution- "Try a basic replacement"

Comment: See the answer below, I think it is all you need.

Comment: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/reading-xml-with-the-xmlreader-class/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote this is ASP.NET. You can use Linq2Xml to perform this operation very quickly (LinqPad example):

```
void Main()
{
    var test = XDocument.Parse("<root><node name=\"name value\">Text</node></root>");
    foreach(var attr in test.Descendants().SelectMany(el=>el.Attributes("name")))
                attr.Remove();

    test.Dump();
}
```

So from this:

```
<root>
  <node name="name value">Text</node>
</root>
```

You get this:

```
<root>
  <node>Text</node>
</root>
```

The snippet will remove ALL name attributes from every single element in the XML aside of the root one. If you want to do something else (like just empty the attribute, or include the root element), let me know.

Comment: I chose your answer because it more related to my project(asp.net)
Thanks

Comment: @EranMeir: Next time, don't forget to tag your question properly, please.

Answer (score 2):

[Don't parse XML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1030675). Use an XML aware tool.

For example, in [xsh](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), you can achieve this with

```
open file.xml ;
rm //@Name ;
save :b ;
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I'm just a maintainer.

Comment: i can't add libraries to this project

Comment: How can i use it within an asp.net project ?

Comment: @EranMeir: You didn't say it's an asp.net project. But see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209834/launch-a-program-from-asp-net-c-sharp on how to use anything.

Comment: as i said. i can't add any lib or alike to this project.

Answer (score 1):

Try this RegEx:

```
Name=\"(.*?)\"
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please share it with [this tool](http://regexr.com/) or other tool (showing the example? 
i cant manage to get it to work

Comment: @EranMeir the link you have added is for Javascript regex only. Try this link - https://myregextester.com/. I am unable to save test in this url.

Comment: You can use [Regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester) to share links to .NET regex

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, I ave tested it but unable to save.

Comment: i am getting "0 matches found"

Comment: See [this link](http://goo.gl/IKqksc) showing my suggestion. You can remove the `Name` completely like that. See the *Context* tab to see the replacement result.

Comment: i need "Name=" to be selected also