# How to run VBScript or Powershell script on IIS web page?

Tags: powershell, iis, vbscript

I have set up `IIS` on a `Win 10` machine.

All I want to do is have a site with one page that runs a `VBScript` or `Powershell` script on the machine.

How can I do this simply?

Comment: You can't run anything like that from inside internet explorer. You can run it inside the IIS process. Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209834/launch-a-program-from-asp-net-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

It exists [PowerShell Web Server](http://www.poshserver.net/). It's a Secure, flexible and lightweight web server that should meet your requirements.

In a few minutes you will be able to have a site with one page, I use it to publish my daily stats.

Comment: Is that project still maintained? Seems like a while since it was last updated. Neat to know that exists though.

Comment: I don't think we are much users. Have a look to the sources, it's quite simple, I'am able to maintain it myself. I mainly use it for tooling, not for public a WEB. The developer Yusuf Ozturk seems to be available.